# No output for Julia program in Juno IDE

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I'm trying to run a very simple Julia program containing only **println("Hello world")** in Juno IDE. It seems the code keeps running and no output is ever produced. However, when I type the snippet in the REPL window it immediately produces the desired output. I looked into the following tutorial in order to set up Juno in Atom on a 64-bit windows 10 pc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8EFeY0odlQ&list=PLJ39kWiJXSiyegKeVd-praE_jOv6sgCn5

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: That sometimes happens to me too I usually just restart atom. Make sure the Julia process has time to initialize properly before you start evaluating in the editor, it seems it's mostly happening if you eval during initialization.

Comment: For me, it is not the case because I tried running the snippet (shift+enter) after I saw Julia prompt. The cogwheel symbol on the right of the snippet never goes away

Comment: For the experience with my colleagues, I think in Windows it is best to use the Juliapro bundle that ships with both Julia and Juno already set to work nicely together..